# Android: Extracting tiles from a tileset programatically?

Tags: android

How do I programatically extract tiles from a tileset such as this one: http://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/grassland_tiles.png

I want to use these tiles in my game. I see that some tiles here are of different sizes (or maybe all tiles are a multiple of some fixed size). For example, if I want to use one of the tree tiles in my program, how can I figure out what offset into the tileset image I must use, and how big of a sub-image i must extract? I don't see any metadata associated with any of these tilesets that I can use.

Also, is there an Android API I can use to extract a part of an image from a bigger image?

Thanks!

Comment: That png is meant as a preview rather than a real sprite sheet. Your best bet would be to post to the opengameart.org forums and ask them for a tutorial on how to use their resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. I missed the following line on the page I got this png from:

> To use the tile set in Tiled v0.8, get the necessary files from the
>   Flare git repo.

The git repro in question is [here](https://github.com/clintbellanger/flare/tree/master/tiled/grassland), which seems to have several metadata files which describe the tileset.

Thanks to everyone who commented.